# python list into custom json formatting

Tags: python, json

I have a  below list in python :

```
response = [{u'Owner Name': u'Ashish Bainade', u'Unit ID': u'102', u'Wing': 
u'B'}, {u'Owner Name': u'Sagar Dhondhe', u'Unit ID': u'104', u'Wing': u'B'}, 
{u'Owner Name': u'Akshara Bainade', u'Unit ID': u'105', u'Wing': u'D'}]
```

I have to send response in below json format:

```
Wings : [ { "wing name" :"B",Flat : [{"Unit ID" : 102 , "owner name" : 
"Ashish Bainade"},{"Unit ID" : 104 , "owner name" : "Sagar Dhondhe"} ] },
  { "wing name" :"D",Flat : [{"Unit ID" : 105 , "owner name" : "Akshara 
Bainade"}] 
}]
```

Comment: show your attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the dicts using the `'Wing'` field and then build the new data structure excluding that field from each nested dict:

```
from itertools import groupby

group_by_field = 'Wing'
f = lambda x: x[group_by_field]  

result = [{'Wing name': k, 
           'Flat': [{k: d[k] for k in set(d)-{group_by_field,}} for d in g]} 
                             for k, g in groupby(sorted(response, key=f), f)]
print(result)
```

---

```
[{'Flat': [{'Owner Name': 'Ashish Bainade', 'Unit ID': '102'},
           {'Owner Name': 'Sagar Dhondhe', 'Unit ID': '104'}],
  'Wing name': 'B'},
 {'Flat': [{'Owner Name': 'Akshara Bainade', 'Unit ID': '105'}],
  'Wing name': 'D'}]
```

Presorting is required to use `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: you are great man,I was trying it from last 3 hours:)
you saved my day:) have a great day ahead.